# In Grails, how to get the total result count when we are passing max and offset values to the list method?

Tags: grails, pagination

If I understand correctly, we can retrieve the desired number of specific results for pagination by passing the max and offset values to the `list` method. But, in many cases, we also want to show the total number of results returned by the SQL query. As per my understanding, with the offset and max values passed to the `list` method, the SQL query still returns all the results internally but the results are trimmed according to the max and offset values. Is there any way to get the total number of results returned before trimming occurs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When max is specified, list() method returns PagedResultList  which has a totalCount property

```
def list = DomainClass.list(params) { }
log.debug "Total records: $list.totalCount"    
render view:'list', model: [list:list, totalRecords:list.totalCount]
```

Answer (score 5):

You do not understand correctly :)

It would be crazy to retrieve all of the records to count them and filter out the ones that shouldn't have been returned at the client. It wouldn't be that bad with a few rows, but consider the performance implications of an approach like that with tables that have millions or billions of rows.

Instead, you have to execute two queries. One to retrieve the rows that you want, doing the filtering *in the database*, and another with the same where clause restrictions but without the max and offset values, and using `select count ...`.

As @sudhir points out in his answer, Grails will return a custom `List` implementation (`PagedResultList`) which includes the results for the current page and has a `getTotalCount` method to return the result from the count query.

The implementation of the `list` method is [here](https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/blob/master/grails-datastore-gorm/src/main/groovy/org/grails/datastore/gorm/GormStaticApi.groovy#L413) and you can see in the [PagedResultList](https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/blob/master/grails-datastore-gorm/src/main/groovy/grails/gorm/PagedResultList.java) source that the count query is lazily run only when you call `getTotalCount`.

Answer (score 1):

**Grails Criteria Query and pagination params**

```
params.max = params?.max as Integer ?: 10
params.offset = params?.offset as Integer ?: 0
params.sort = params?.sort ?: "email"
params.order = params?.order ?: "asc"
params.filter = params?.filter ?: ""
params.packet = params?.packet ?: ""

def members = Member.createCriteria().list(params)
  {
    or
    {
      if(params.filter != ""){
        ilike("firstName", "%" + params.filter + "%")
        ilike("lastName", "%" + params.filter + "%")
        ilike("email", "%" + params.filter + "%")
        try {
          params.filter as Long
          eq("citizenId" , params.filter.toLong())
        }catch (e) {

        }
        ilike("mobile", "%" + params.filter + "%")
      }
    }
  }

def dataMembers = [:]
dataMembers.data = members
dataMembers.totalRecord = members.totalCount
render dataMembers as JSON
```

**Output**

```
{
"data": [
    {
      "id":1,
      "firstName":name
    },
    {
      "id":2,
      "firstName":name
    }
  ],
"totalRecord":5
}
```

Comment: A bit of explanation with your code or what you have changed would be helpful.

Comment: Good example, but the max and offset parameters are not used.